# No internet access when modem reboots

Tags: router, internet, modem, adsl, cable-modem

I have a cable modem (A) given by my ISP (which has only 1 RJ 45 Ethernet port along with the ISPs cable input port) a [modem+router](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=451) (B) and another [router](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=677) (C). A lan cable connects A to B, another connects B to C, and finally my desktop is also connected to B through lan cable. 
All my wifi devices use C's wireless network. Whenever I perform a factory reset on B, evrything works fine and all devices are able to access Internet. But whenever I restart A and B (both share the same power outlet), no device is able to access Internet. Any clues as to what's wrong here?

Comment: You need to restart A and B in the correct order. A first (and wait until it is fully up) and then B second.

Comment: @DavidPostill That worked. But the purpose of restarting router was to just simply simulate brief power cuts that happen rarely in my area. Is there a way to automatically delay-start the B router so that I don't have to do this every time?

Comment: Not that I know of. If they really are brief power cuts buying a UPS might resolve it for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill Also, I cannot access B router's settings when I have internet access, but can access settings it when there is no Internet access.

Comment: IP address is different?

Comment: @DavidPostill A- 192.168.0.2        B- 192.168.1.1            C- 192.168.0.1

Comment: There you go. B is on a different subnet.

Comment: @DavidPostill So I should change B to 192.168.0.something  ?

Comment: @DavidPostill [This](http://dlink2730uaccesspoint.blogspot.com/2016/06/let-configure-our-dlink-2730u-wifi-adsl.html?m=1) link along with changing B's ip address solvd the problem. The question may be closed now.

Comment: We don't close question when they are resolved as they are there for future readers. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) using the information in your comment.

Comment: Agree with @davidpostill, get a UPS for your network gear. Also low quality power has a tendency to burnout wall-adapters and in some cases damage the equipment.